# DotNet not valid certificate found

Tags: c#, .net-core, https

I have seen this questions many times, but none of the answers works for me.
My DotNet Core app fails

The code:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
AccionesWeb.Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs
```

When I try to create a cert, it creates it without problem, but then it says `not found`

```
PS ...> dotnet dev-certs https -t
Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully.

PS ...> dotnet dev-certs https -c
No valid certificate found.
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution.
I had to manually delete all certs because `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` was not removing all of them

If you are facing this issue, delete all `localhost` certificates with **friendly name** `ASP.NET Core...` from:

- Current User > Personal > Certificates
- Current User > Trusted root certification authorities > Certificates

More info in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#windows---certificate-not-trusted)

Comment: Tried this and still had no luck.  Still says there are no valid certificates when running `--check`

Comment: @DavidPeterson do you have any DotNet certificate in the cert store? let me know if you are not sure how to check it

Comment: I had read through the answer too quickly and realized I missed where you need to check _Personal_ certificates as well.  After finding more certs there, I was able to remedy the issue.  I had forgot I wrote this, otherwise I would have updated it.

Comment: In Mac Os, I deleted the localhost certificates in the System tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sudherson for sharing the tip!