# After running dev-certs https --trust, dotnet run complains that the default developer certificate could not be found

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, windows-10, dotnet-cli

We read [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos).

We ran the following in PowerShell:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
dotnet dev-certs https --check # none found :-(
```

Then we opened a new PowerShell session and ran this:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --check # still none found :-(
dotnet run
```

This is the error message.

> `System.InvalidOperationException`: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

Here is the output of `dotnet --info`

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.302
 Commit:    c005824e35

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.302\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.8
  Commit:  35964c9215
```

How can we point `dotnet run` to the certificate that we created with `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`?

Comment: does this solve your problem ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266363/dotnet-not-valid-certificate-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/65266499/1108891, we manually deleted all certificates that localhost issued and then repeated our steps. This is how we deleted all localhost issued certs.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser -Recurse `
| Where { $_.PSISContainer -eq $false } `
| Where { $_.Issuer -match 'localhost' } `
| Remove-Item -Whatif;

 Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine -Recurse `
| Where { $_.PSISContainer -eq $false } `
| Where { $_.Issuer -match 'localhost' } `
| Remove-Item -Whatif
```

The `-Whatif` is there to avoid copy/paste from clobbering an unwitting reader's certificate store. We removed it when we ran this step.